# Why do you need crt2.o in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, mingw

Programm Hello World (hello.s)

```
    .data
LC0:
    .ascii "Hello, World!\0"
    .text
    .globl  _main
_main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $16, %esp
    movl    $LC0, (%esp)
    call    _puts
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

1 compilation method

```
as.exe hello.s
ld -s a.out -LC:\gcc\lib -lmsvcrt -o hello.exe(2kb)
```

2 compilation method(standart)

```
as.exe hello.s
gcc -s a.out -o hello.exe(12kb)
```

I found that the increase in the size of hello.exe is associated with the attachment of the crt2.o file. What specific function does it perform?

Comment: Have a read of [Freestanding and hosted implementations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/freestanding) .  Initialising the Runtime Support library, setting the state and attaching the console IO etc. Note that `_main` is not the true entry point of the program, it's called from the real entry point in the Runtime Support library after it's initialisation has been done.

Comment: I don't see anything C++-related here. You are not even using `g++`. What is the reason for the tag instead of `c` or `assembly`?